# Understanding the grammar of 潜みし

Tags: grammar

In the sentence 白雪に潜みし影, what is the function of し? I understand that it is derived from 潜む (be hidden, concealed), but I don't get why it is conjugated into い段 and has し attached to it. Is it poetic or maybe old language?